Mini fridge cooled to 35, then has stayed between 45-50
Danby DAR044A8BBSL
Hello! I'm very confused about this issue as the fridge did indeed reach around 35°F but then stayed around 45°F - 50°F.
I cleaned it out and defrosted the inside. While cleaning the metal drip pan I noticed it was cracked. I put it back in and turned it back on and left the fridge empty while it started to cool. I put in a thermostat and it shows that the temperature did go down to about 35°F with around 20% humidity. Then it suddenly started going up and went up to between 45°F to 50°F and about 65% humidity. I put things inside the fridge and it cooled down and has stayed between 45°F to 50°F and humidity 30% to 90% I know it cools down to 35°F, why did it suddenly spike up and not cool down to 35°F anymore?

Bad seal? Bad insulation? Has the temperature in the room containing the fridge increased so it would have to work harder to cook?

But if it were either one of those things, would it have been able to go down to 35? Also, the temperature was stable in the room

Presumably you opened and closed the door at least once. If it didn't seal well the second time.... Speculation.

I didn't close/open the door, that's what's confusing me. It's as if it hit a temperature and then it started rising

How are you checking the thermostat without opening the door?  What times (of day) were you getting these temperatures?  What was the humidity outside of the refrigerator at those times?  What kind of thermostat are you using?

It's not working correctly or safely, so contact the manufacturer for a replacement or service, if it's new. If not new enough to be under warranty, it may be a low-end fridge that costs less than a service call does, which means it's junk.

Or perhaps it has a new life as a wine cooler since that's more or less in "cellar temperatures" range.
